# Anonymous + Unknown User attempt to my DB

Tags: mysql, errors

I was checking my MySQL log and I found this error:

> Connect  UNKNOWN_MYSQL_US@localhost as anonymous on

Is it normal? Should I worry about a possible attack?

Answer (score 0):

It's not Anonymous account

It is normal behavior from MySQL core.

Look at this:
https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.5/packaging/rpm-oel/mysql.init#L67

It's for pinging MySQL to check MySQL is running or not